# UITextField being clipped during CABasicAnimation with keyPath of bounds.size.width

Tags: ios, uitextfield, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I have a somewhat of an odd issue on hand. I have UITextField. This TextField has it’s width resized when a button is tapped. To do that I first did the following:

```
CGRect newbounds = originalBounds;
newbounds.size.width = newbounds.size.width/2;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
self.textField2.bounds = newbounds;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Easy enough and it worked. Now I move along and try to exert a bit more control over the animation. To do that I go the next level up to CABasicAnimation using the following:

```
CGRect newbounds = originalBounds;
newbounds.size.width = newbounds.size.width/2;

CABasicAnimation *animShrink = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animShrink.keyPath = @"bounds";
animShrink.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:newbounds];
animShrink.duration = 0.5;
animShrink.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
animShrink.delegate = self;

[self.textField2.layer addAnimation:animShrink forKey:@"shrink"];
```

And that is when I run into the clipping issue during the animation as can be seen at: http://coldstorage.macbonsai.com/public/cabasic_animation_clipping.png (since I “need at least 10 reputation to post images” as per Stackoverflow).

So I tried the following version of the animation:

```
CGRect newbounds = originalBounds;
newbounds.size.width = newbounds.size.width/2;

CABasicAnimation *animShrink = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animShrink.keyPath = @"bounds.size.width";
animShrink.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:originalBounds.size.width];
animShrink.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:newbounds.size.width];
animShrink.duration = 0.5;
animShrink.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
animShrink.delegate = self;

[self.textField2.layer addAnimation:animShrink forKey:@"shrink"];
```

Still encountered the same issue. At this point I removed all constraints from the UITextField and tried both the CABasicAnimation versions. Same issue. At this point I don’t know what else to do. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?
I'm having the exact same problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you change the style of the button to UITextBorderStyleNone it doesn't get clipped.

My guess is that when the style is UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect, Apple probably just adds a UIImageView to the button with the "round rect" image, so when you animate the button's layer, its subviews don't animate together, because in iOS you have to explicitly animate all sublayers.